# React useState using object data type

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, use-state, react-forms

So I am new to React and I am currently working on forms. Firstly this is the entire code I wrote:

```
 const [optionGender, setOptionGender] = useState({value: '', label: ''});
 const options = [
     {value: 'male', label:'male'},
     {value: 'female', label: 'female'}
 ]

 return (
     <>
         <h3>Personal Information</h3>

         <Formik initialValues = {{
             firstName: '',
             lastName: '',
             email: '',
             gender: optionGender,
             age: '',
         }}
             onSubmit = {value => {
                 console.log(value);
                 // when the form is posted
             }}
             validationSchema = {Yup.object({
                 firstName: Yup.string().required("This field is required")
             })}
         >
             <Form>
                 <div className= "mb-3">
                     <label htmlFor = "firstName">First Name</label>
                     <Field name = "firstName" id = "firstName" placeholder = "First Name" className="form-control"/>
                     <ErrorMessage name = "firstName">{msg => <div className = "text-danger"> {msg}</div>}</ErrorMessage>
                     <label htmlFor="lastName">Last Name</label>
                     <Field name = "lastName" id = "lastName" placeholder = "Last Name" className="form-control"/>
                     <label htmlFor="gender">Gender</label>
                     <Select name = "gender" id = "gender" placeholder = "Select ..." options = {options} onChange = {(e) => {
                         setOptionGender({
                             value: e?.value
                             label: e?.label
                         })
                     }}/>
                     <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
                     <Field name = "email" id = "email" placeholder = "Email Address"className="form-control"/>
                     <label htmlFor="age">Age</label>
                     <Field name = "age" id = "age" placeholder = "Age" className="form-control"/>
                 </div>

                 <Button type = "submit"> Save Changes</Button>
                 <Link className = "btn btn-secondary" to = "/">Cancel</Link>
             </Form>
         </Formik>        
     </>
 )
```

Basically I am trying to change the option value which is an object of {value: sting, label:string} and pass the new value to gender variable of the form. But I have the following error:

> Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
> Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)

The problem is in code

```
                             value: e?.value
                             label: e?.label
```

Any solutions?
Thank you

Comment: Try `value: e?.value || ''`

Answer (score 0):

Why would you like to save the label, too?

Anyways, for debugging you could log your event to see how it is structured:

```
onChange={(e) => {
  console.log(e);
  ...
}}
```

Since we do not know what UI framework you are using for rendering the  component (and therefore see what they are firing as event), I can only give you what I imagine will work:

```
onChange={(e) => setOptionGender({
  value: e.target.value,
  label: e.target.value
})}
```